# MongoDB query to find documents with variations

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, regex-group

Example MongoDB document:

```
{
  name: "something"
  product: "ABC-123"
}
```

The problem is that product may not always follow the same naming convention. It could be any of the following

```
"ABC-123"
"ABC123"
"ABC 123"
```

So if I search for "ABC-123", I want any document similarly matching regardless of the variation in naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** You can simply use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in your query using the expression`^ABC(?:.*?)\\d+$`, like so:

Example MongoDB document:

```
db={
  "products": [
    {
      "name": "product A",
      "product": "ABC-123"
    },
    {
      "name": "product B",
      "product": "ABC123"
    },
    {
      "name": "product C",
      "product": "ABC-123"
    }
  ]
}
```

Query:

```
db.products.find({
  "product": {
    "$regex": "^ABC(?:.*?)\\d+$"
  }
})
```

Demo: https://mongoplayground.net/p/WdqTg7LCZIk

---

We might be able to find an expression for this problem. Maybe, let's start with an expression similar to:

```
product:\s+"(.+?)"
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qzTcEM/1)

Here, we are using `product:\s+"` as the left boundary, then we collect any chars, then we bound it from right with `"`.

```js
const regex = /product:\s+"(.+?)"/gm;
const str = `{
  name: "something"
  product: "ABC-123"
}`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Or we can extend it to what we like to capture and not to capture:

```
(?:product:\s+")(.+?)(?:")
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/SP97OM/1/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you variation is just that and those are your 3 possibilities then the answer from **Emma** is just what you need. Another option you have if the regular expression gets out of hand and you end up having a **lot of different product variations** is [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html) search/index AND regEx.

For example:

```
db.getCollection('COLNAME').find({
  $or: [
    {
      $text: {$search: 'abc'}  // By default it is case insensitive
    },
    {
      product: {"$regex": "YOUR_REGEX_HERE"}
    }
  ]
})
```

This would be also performant since you would have a text index on `product` as well as a regular index. This would also take care of cases like `XXX-ABC` and any other variation you might not know/have. So something to think about.